# Table Layout not showing:

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I was creating an app which has a number pad.

**XML CODE**

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appIco"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="74dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:contentDescription="app image"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appName"
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="74dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appIco" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pinField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="266dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/custom_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeField"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:shadowColor="#80000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="12:34"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="60sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayField"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:shadowColor="#80000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="SATURDAY," />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/custom_color"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pinField"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pinField"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.491">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_one_48dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_two_48dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_three_48dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/four"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_four_48dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/five"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_five_48dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/six"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_six_48dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/eight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_eight_48dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/seven"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_seven_48dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/nine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_nine_48dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/backSp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_backspace_white_48dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/zero"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_zero_48dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/done"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_check_white_48dp" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The desired output should be somewhat like this: [image: How It SH=hould Be]

But the keypad is not being shown in the output: [image]

Here is the java code:

```
ImageButton one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,zero,done,backSp;
TableLayout tb;
TableRow tr1,tr2,tr3,tr4;
EditText password;
TextView time,day,appName,timer;
ImageView appIco;
Intent i;
Receiver r;
int wrongCounter,c,maxWrong,maxLength;
boolean quick_unlock = true;
String pass = "1234";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pin_app_lock);
    setup();
    Setter();
    passwordInputHandler();

}

private void setup(){




    tb  = findViewById(R.id.tb);
    tr1 = tb.findViewById(R.id.tr1);
    tr2 = tb.findViewById(R.id.tr2);
    tr3 = tb.findViewById(R.id.tr3);
    tr4 = tb.findViewById(R.id.tr4);

    one = tr1.findViewById(R.id.one);
    two = tr1.findViewById(R.id.two);
    three = tr1.findViewById(R.id.three);
    four = tr2.findViewById(R.id.four);
    five = tr2.findViewById(R.id.five);
    six = tr2.findViewById(R.id.six);
    seven = tr3.findViewById(R.id.seven);
    eight = tr3.findViewById(R.id.eight);
    nine = tr3.findViewById(R.id.nine);
    zero = tr4.findViewById(R.id.zero);
    done = tr4.findViewById(R.id.done);
    backSp = tr4.findViewById(R.id.backSp);

    appIco = findViewById(R.id.appIco);
    appName = findViewById(R.id.appName);
    timer = findViewById(R.id.timer);
    password = findViewById(R.id.pinField);
    time = findViewById(R.id.timeField);
    day = findViewById(R.id.dayField);

    i=getIntent();
    r=new Receiver();

    wrongCounter=0;
    c=0;
    maxWrong = 3;
    maxLength = 4;
    password.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
}

//Sets Time,App Icon
private void Setter(){
    final Handler someHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    someHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            time.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.US).format(new Date()));
            //   time.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).format(new Date()));//HH for 24 hrs clock
            someHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 10);
    someHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String str = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.US).format(new Date());
            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("sun")){str="SUNDAY, ";}
            else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("mon")){str="MONDAY, ";}
            else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("tue")){str="TUESDAY, ";}
            else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("wed")){str="WEDNESDAY, ";}
            else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("thu")){str="THURSDAY, ";}
            else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("fri")){str="FRIDAY, ";}
            else{str="SATURDAY, ";}
            String str1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd", Locale.US).format(new Date()).toUpperCase();
            if(str.substring(0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("mar")){str+="MARCH"+str1.substring(3);}
            else if(str.substring(0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("apr")){str+="APRIL"+str1.substring(3);}
            else if(str.substring(0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("jun")){str+="JUNE"+str1.substring(3);}
            else if(str.substring(0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("jul")){str+="JULY"+str1.substring(3);}
            else if(str.substring(0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("aug")){str+="AUGUST"+str1.substring(3);}
            else{str+=str1;}

            day.setText(str);
            someHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 10);



    try
    {
        Drawable d = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(i.getStringExtra("pname"));
        appIco.setImageDrawable(d);
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.e("PACKAGE NOT FOUND","PACKAGE NOT FOUND");
    }

    appName.setText(i.getStringExtra("appName"));


}

//Password Edittext Handling
private void passwordInputHandler(){

    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            password.setText(password.getText()+"1");
        }
    });

    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            password.setText(password.getText()+"2");
        }
    });

    three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            password.setText(password.getText()+"3");
        }
    });

    four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            password.setText(password.getText()+"4");
        }
    });

    five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            password.setText(password.getText()+"5");
        }
    });

    six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            password.setText(password.getText()+"6");
        }
    });

    seven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            password.setText(password.getText()+"7");
        }
    });

    eight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            password.setText(password.getText()+"8");
        }
    });

    nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            password.setText(password.getText()+"9");
        }
    });

    zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            password.setText(password.getText()+"0");
        }
    });

    backSp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            password.setText(password.getText().toString().substring(0, password.getText().toString().length() - 1));
        }
    });



}
```

So can anyone please tell me ehats the problem?

Comment: In you XML Code, I don't see the close tag for ConstraintLayout. Can you correct that?

Comment: The easiest way to get what you want to is to nest everything in a root linear layout.... with that you really should think about making each discrete piece a fragment...

Comment: maybe you can check your drawable, i just replaced your drawable with some random drawable ex ic_eight_48dp, its works fine as your expected layout.

Comment: Not related to your question: 1. You do not need to get the rows, unless there is some reason you use them later in your code other than to get the numbered buttons. You can just do `one = findViewById(R.id.one);`, for example. 2. You should create an array for the numbered buttons. This will allow you to use loops and have a natural `int` value associated with each button.

Comment: Hey, @snowCrabs I didn't get you totally. I tried putting it inside a linear layout but the output is the same

Comment: @SayokMajumder you need to place things in a linear layout and play with the weights of the views

Comment: Hey, guys got the answer. I was extending Activity instead of that I extended AppCompatActivity and its showing now. Thanks everyone for spending their vital time to review my question.